# PDFsharp MigraDoc Fonts not working in Azure Web App

Tags: c#, azure, pdfsharp, migradoc

VS2017 .NET 4.7

I have written a Web App that creates a PDF, the only related nuget package I have installed is:

**PDFsharp-MigrDoc-GDI v1.32.4334**

It works fine locally on my development machine.

But when I published it to Azure I get the error:

**Font data could not be retrieved.**

I have found that I need to include the fonts I use as resources in the code, as they may not be present on Azure.

I have also found this:

https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/master/src/PdfSharp/Fonts/PlatformFontResolver.cs

But I am starting to get confused.  Which packages do I need?  Do I need PDFsharp, MigraDoc or both?

Any help pointing me in the right direction would help. OR. A simple example "Hello World" PDF (using PDFsharpe/MigraDoc) solution which works on a Azure Web App.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MigraDoc is a set of APIs to create documents.

PDFsharp is a library that creates PDF files.

If you use the MigraDoc API, you will need MigraDoc and PDFsharp. If you only use the PDFsharp API, then you only need the package that includes PDFsharp, but not MigraDoc.

To use IFontResolver, you need the WPF build version 1.50 or higher.

With MigraDoc:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-MigraDoc-wpf/1.50.4845-RC2a

Just PDFsharp:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFsharp-wpf/1.50.4845-RC2a

EZFontResolver may help to simplify using IFontResolver:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3244

The PDFsharp samples include a FontResolver sample that loads fonts from resources:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples

Comment: Thank you.  I have started to make progress using IFontResolver.  I'm now just trying to work out how to reference the 'VERDANA.TTF' (for example) embedded resource from my web page.  I am assuming I need to use Server.MapPath(@"~/PdfFonts/VERDANA.TTF"). Working on it.

Comment: AIUI you need `MapPath` when the font is included on the file system. When you embed it as a resource, you can load it into a `byte[]` without accessing any file. You can check how the PDFsharp FontResolver sample does it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the GetFont(string faceName) function. LoadFontData(... path to font''...)  its the "path to font" I cannot work out.  I have it in "~/PdfFonts/VERDANA.TTF"

Comment: Not my area of expertise. AFAIK "~" requires MapPath used properly to find the file. The FontResolver sample included in the PDFsharp samples uses font in resources and works completely without MapPath (and that's rather my area of expertise).

Comment: Yes, I'm homing in on it.  I just can't work out what to put in the LoadFontData("MyWebApiProject.PdfFonts.VERDANA.TTF"); field to get it to find the font.

Comment: Thank guys, I got it in the end following the examples you provided.  My last issue was that I had put my font resources in a different project, hence  var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); Was getting the wrong one.